# Is there anyway to prevent some event fired before end of another event?

Tags: c#, events, datagridview

In the code below the SelectionChanged event is fired before the end of RowsAdded,how can I make the Event atomic?

```
private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[1];
        dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[1].Selected = true;
    }

private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow != null)
        {
            //Something
        }
    }
```

what should i do?

Comment: You should start by explaining what you're trying to achieve, and explaining what *is* happening more clearly. Your question is very confusing at the moment.

Comment: @JonSkeet I rephrased the question!

Comment: You haven't rephrased it *well*. You may no what's going on, but I still don't. A short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem would help for one thing - as well as a clearer statement of what you're trying to achieve. "Making the event atomic" is *not* a clear statement. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @JonSkeet You know if add a row to an empty dataGridView1 both events will be fired,right?(because selection is changed and also a row is added)
The thing i need is that first RowsAdded statements be executed and completed then SelectionChanged executed.not in the middle of each other.

Comment: I wouldn't actually expect the selection to be fired *just* by adding the row, without any other code executing. (It's not really *selected* as such, is it?) But then again, if you'd supplied a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, I'd have been able to experiment easily for myself. As it is, I've had to spend ages trying to persuade you to clarify your question (which you still haven't, really) so I now don't have time. Maybe someone else will understand your question better...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SelectionChanged` is fired in the middle of handling `RowsAdded` because you are causing a SelectionChanged by changing the current cell *within* `dataGridView1_RowsAdded`.  Adding a row doesn't cause both events to be fired -- you're causing the second event while handling the first one.  (In fact, you're probably causing `SelectionChanged` twice, because both lines in the handler seem to change the selection).

If you don't want `dataGridView1_SelectionChanged` running while in the RowsAdded handler, you need to either temporarily unsubscribe from the event:

```
dataGridView1.SelectionChanged -= dataGridView1_SelectionChanged;
// change the selection... 
dataGridView1.SelectionChanged += dataGridView1_SelectionChanged;
```

Or even better, re-design what you're doing inside the SelectionChanged handler so that it is appropriate for all instances of the event.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the event you want to conrol and then put an if condition in the overriden event and control when it fires and when it does not.
mahdi